# I want to fetch logs like activity, key-vault,nsg flow log from azure monitor with the help of java program and send them to an tcp/http endpoint

Tags: java, azure, logging, azure-monitoring, azure-nsg

I want to get the real time log data from azure monitor but unable to find the structure and api in java for this.
The program will run as cron and pull the different logs from azure monitor.

what will be the structure/api's for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of Azure logs and different ways where you can route these logs and hence different ways to retrieve them.  For example, in general you can create a diagnostic setting to route Azure resource logs to the Log Analytics feature within Azure Monitor and use Log Analytics REST API to retrieve the logs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-platform-logs